# ng-repeat with an orderBy not working for me after v1.3.0-beta.13

Tags: angularjs

Has anyone noticed problems with ng-repeat when used in this configuration:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view = (home.grid.data | orderBy:ctrl.contentOrderBy[ctrl.configService.admin.contentOrderBy].key:ctrl.configService.admin.contentSortDirection)">
```

Here is my contentOrderBy object:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"CId","key":"contentId"},
 {"id":1,"name":"Modified By","key":"modifiedBy"},
 {"id":2,"name":"Modified Date","key":"modified"},
 {"id":3,"name":"Status","key":"contentStatusId"},
 {"id":4,"name":"Status > Type","key":["contentStatusId","contentTypeId"]}]
```

ctrl.configService.admin.contentSortDirection has two values: 0 or 1

My problem is when I try to change to configService.admin.contentSortDirection:

- @license AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.8 - works
- AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.12 - works
- AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.13 - works
- AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.14 - does not change direction
- @license AngularJS v1.3.0-rc.5 - does not change direction
- @license AngularJS v1.3.0 - does not change direction

I have checked the latest documentation and unless mistaken I cannot find anything on how to do an orderBy which I thought used to appear in previous documentation.

If anyone else knows of a working way to do this I would appreciate any suggestions. I'm also wonder why the ng-repeat documentation appears to be a bit lacking.

Comment: Did you see the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)?

Comment: Yes I did and I could not find anything that would explain why only this functionality out of over 1,000 tests stops working after beta 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the line:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view = (home.grid.data | orderBy:ctrl.contentOrderBy[ctrl.configService.admin.contentOrderBy].key:ctrl.configService.admin.contentSortDirection)">
```

to:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in home.grid.view = (home.grid.data | orderBy:ctrl.contentOrderBy[ctrl.configService.admin.contentOrderBy].key:ctrl.configService.admin.contentSortDirection == 1)">
```

Harish was on the right track but the way he sets the reverse parameter is completely wrong:

```
reverse=order.dir === 1
```

There is no requirement to put "reverse=".

Your problem is caused by this change in the Beta 14 release:

```
fix(core): drop the toBoolean function
So far Angular have used the toBoolean function to decide if the parsed value
is truthy. The function made more values falsy than regular JavaScript would,
e.g. strings 'f' and 'no' were both treated as falsy. This creates suble bugs
when backend sends a non-empty string with one of these values and something
suddenly hides in the application

Thanks to lgalfaso for test ideas.

BREAKING CHANGE: values 'f', '0', 'false', 'no', 'n', '[]' are no longer
treated as falsy. Only JavaScript falsy values are now treated as falsy by the
expression parser; there are six of them: false, null, undefined, NaN, 0 and "".

Closes #3969
Closes #4277
Closes #7960
```